# Highlighting multiple bars in rep graph does not show data for multiple days

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

#### EDIT

This is either

1. a bug report - it does not work for showing data for multiple days; or
2. a bug report - it should not allow more than one bar to be highlighted; or
3. a feature request - make it show data for all highlighted days

---

**Original title: Is there a secret easter egg here, or nothing to see, move along?**

Thanks to our kind StackExchange overlords, we now have a new rep graph, one that is ostensibly very usable, relevant and appealing.

[image]

I was playing to zooming in and out, which works great (Jon hasn't hit 1000 in one day yet??).  Then I found out that you can click on the (top) graph, turning it gray.

- Is there a game behind it? - Can't crack this.
- Is there a correlation to the by-time "tab"? - doesn't appear to anchor
- Why does Shift-click work exactly the same as Ctrl-click, *against convention*?

Well, is there something more to the clickable gray bars?

Comment: Only jeff hit 1000 on meta, IIRC.

Comment: This is Jon on SO. I think I have seen other users go beyond 1000..

Comment: @YOU Only Oleg hit 1000 on SO

Comment: thanks for info, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clicking filters the rep entries below to show only what happened on that day.  It seems to me that being able to select multiple bars is a bug as it only shows the rep changes from the last day you clicked.

BTW, this is hardest to notice on very populated graphs like Jon Skeet's.

Comment: Ah... on a notebook 1280x800, Firefox fills the page exactly baselining just below the lower graph. Didn't even see that there was anything under it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** You may find the numbers to be slightly off when compared against the users' rep page/graph.  This is due to various shortcomings of the data.stackexchange dump.  In particular:

When bounty award was disconnected from acceptance, the acceptance vote is no longer generated. In the old bounty award scenario before this change, the acceptance vote does **NOT** carry a +15 rep change.

Compare the two users Oleg and Nick in the list below (positions 1 and 3) in this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1154/bounty-award-disconnect-from-acceptance-rep-handling
Oleg's 2 bounty awards (May 2010) were followed immediately by an accept vote (accept.vote.id = bounty.vote.id+1), whereas Nick's (Nov 2010) doesn't. The query that produced the list did not take this into account.  It also does not account for downvotes cast, which has a maximum per-day impact of -30.

---

Useless trivia.. tangential to question, as response to [YOU](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/you)'s comment

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/96186/ against Data.SE with latest post dated 22/23-March-2011

```
UserID        Name            Total  Bounty  Achieved on   Actual
315935        Oleg            1075   950     5/05/2010    ** 1045
142299        Kevin Boyd      970    900     19/03/2010   **  940
13249         Nick Craver     970    500     15/11/2010   **  970
203907        Bozho           900    550     22/03/2010
70604         Pascal Thivent  895    500     20/07/2010
70604         Pascal Thivent  885    550     18/02/2010
13249         Nick Craver     865    500     9/08/2010
138475        Pascal MARTIN   855    550     10/03/2010
118903        Vinay Sajip     825    750     17/08/2009
83667         Jose Basilio    795    550     7/06/2009
126352        Justin Grant    790    700     19/10/2009
18393         cletus          780    550     26/05/2009
118903        Vinay Sajip     775    550     21/07/2009
315935        Oleg            775    500     29/11/2010
6309          VonC            775    500     20/09/2010
21234         skaffman        770    550     14/01/2010
22656         Jon Skeet       770    300     30/06/2009
12744         Colin Pickard   765    550     23/06/2009
12711         Michael Burr    765    550     24/02/2010
45773         Steffen Opel    760    700     24/08/2009
118903        Vinay Sajip     753    550     10/09/2009
157882        BalusC          745    500     20/12/2010
17034         Hans Passant    730    550     23/05/2010
326480        mdma            715    450     21/05/2010
399317        Kos             705    500     12/11/2010
```

Without considering bounties, https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/96190/
The field narrows to Nick Craver, Jon Skeet, Darin Dimitrov