# Reputation graph mishandles shift-click

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph

On the rep graph, shift-clicking the bar for a day selects and highlights it, but it does not remove the highlight on any previously clicked bars.

Allowing selection of multiple days would be a nice new feature, but in any case the highlighting should be kept accurate.

Here's a screenshot demonstrating the problem:
[image: rep graph bug]
Sep 28 is (apparently) selected, but some shift-clicking has caused the summary to show (apparently no selected) Oct 4th.

Comment: Wait, shift-clicking ? I thought that opens the link in a new window? Hmm.. I'n cnfused

Comment: If you click a link, it does, if you click on the bars of the reputation graph, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation it highlights them.

Comment: Wow coool! Man Thank You Very Much! I never even knew of reputation graph! Hmmm, this is probly a browser/OS issue

Comment: Related: [Highlighting multiple bars in rep graph does not show data for multiple days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85105)